# Peltier module not cooling

Tags: peltier

I have a peltier (12705) and I have created adequate cooling for the hot side and a small heatsink and fan on the cold side. The cold side reaches -12°C.

I have a cutout in a small box that the cold side is in with the hot side outside of the box.
For some reason, even though the cold side heatsink is below 0°C, the small fan is not blowing cold air from it and the box is staying a temperature of 16°C.

I have checked and there are no air holes for warm air to get in.

Why is the box not cooling down?

Comment: If the cold side sink is <0 C then you don't have an electronics problem. If the box is staying well above 0 C, you have a physics problem.

Comment: Also consider that Peltier junctions are most efficient when the temperature difference between their sides is 0 degrees.  Because of this, large temperature differences (hot and cold) are best handled with two or more modules stacked on top of each other.